# Typecasting in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, apollo-client

I have the following TypeScript code to create an ApolloClient:

```
return new ApolloClient({
    dataIdFromObject: (o) => o.uuid
});
```

The compiler is giving me the following error:

> TS2339:Property 'uuid' does not exist on type 'Object'

I tried to typecast as follows:

```
interface DomainObject {
    uuid: string
}
...
return new ApolloClient({
    dataIdFromObject: (<DomainObject>o) => o.uuid
});
```

But now the compiler gets very confused and several lines around the code, which were fine before are starting to give errors. Specifically, the cast above gives this error:

> TS17008:JSX element '' has no corresponding closing tag

Apparently it thinks that this is JSX code.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `o` here is a parameter declaration, not an expression. Try `(o: DomainObject) => o.uuid`

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, thanks for clarifying. Works like a charm! If you could put that as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type assertions are only valid on expressions. `o` here is a parameter declaration, not an expression (`o => o.uuid` is a lambda). But you can give a type *annotation* to a parameter:

```
return new ApolloClient({
    dataIdFromObject: (o: DomainObject) => o.uuid
});
```